# Could not cast value of type '__NSTaggedDate' to 'NSNumber'

Tags: ios, swift

I have an array of dictionaries which have a `NSDate` key and a `Double` value (`[NSDictionary]`) and I want to calculate the sum of all values like so:

```
let sum = results.flatMap { $0.allValues.map { $0 as! Double } }.reduce(0, +)
```

But I am getting this weird error:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSTaggedDate' to 'NSNumber'
```

Anyone knows what the issue is with my sum calculation ?

edit:

The values that I am getting are from Core Data. This is how I retrieve them:

```
  let amountExpr = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "amount")
    let sumExpr = NSExpression(forFunction: "sum:", arguments: [amountExpr])
    let sumDescr = NSExpressionDescription()
    sumDescr.expression = sumExpr
    sumDescr.name = "sumOfAmount"
    sumDescr.expressionResultType = .doubleAttributeType

    let dateExpr = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "date")
    let dateDescr = NSExpressionDescription()
    dateDescr.expression = dateExpr
    dateDescr.name = "date"
    dateDescr.expressionResultType = .dateAttributeType

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Transaction")
    request.sortDescriptors = Transaction.defaultSortDescriptors
    request.propertiesToFetch = [dateDescr, sumDescr]
    request.propertiesToGroupBy = [dateDescr]
    request.resultType = .dictionaryResultType
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    request.predicate = Transaction.rangeOfDatesPredicate(dateRange: Date.week())
    let results = try! context.fetch(request) as! [NSDictionary]
```

Comment: Give us a full example. It works for me using

`let results: [NSDictionary] = [NSDictionary(dictionary: [Date(): 9.9]), NSDictionary(dictionary: [Date(): 1.1])];

let sum = results.flatMap { $0.allValues.map { $0 as! Double } }.reduce(0, +);

sum; // 11`

Comment: ok, I have edit my question. Forgot to mention that my results are coming from Core Data.

Comment: Core Data returns dictionaries with `String` keys and – in your case –  `Date` / `Double` values. Map the array to get the `Double` values and add them. By the way `[[String:Any]]` is **much** better than `[NSDictionary]`.

Comment: Can't do that in Playground! Looks like you might need to cast the NSDictionary's elements. Also agree with @Vadian - avoid `NSDictionary` if possible!

Comment: @vadian: I don't understand the part with Core Data returns String as key and Date/Double as value. Value is a dictionary or what does Date / Double means ?

Comment: I updated the answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Core Data `fetch` with `.dictionaryResultType` returns `[[String:Any]]`.

The format of the returned array is:

```
[["dateDescr" : <date1>, "sumDescr" : <double1>], ["dateDescr" : <date2>, "sumDescr" : <double2>]]
```

Map the values for key `sumDescr` and add them and it's always good programming habit to catch a potential error:

```
do {
    let results = try context.fetch(request) as! [[String:Any]]
    let sum = results.map { $0["sumDescr"] as! Double }.reduce(0.0, +)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Ohh, seeing the return format now it makes sense. It's working now.